# Mule Set JSESSIONID from first into 2nd REST request or how to put the cookie through

Tags: rest, cookies, mule, business-process-management, bonita

for my Thesis I'm integrating Bonita BPM into a Mule SOA.

To start a new case or process-instance in Bonita I have to call the Bonita REST. First I have to authenticate with that Bonita REST. And here starts my problem.

The authentication works like "You have to call the loginservice and put the responding cookie in all future request".

How could this be done inside a mule flow ? Some articles told me that copy-properties propertyName="JSESSIONID" should do that. But this does not work.

Does anybody have a idea ?

Further heres my flow and the related print messages:

PRINT1 : CopyPropertiesTransformer: Property value for is null, no property will be copied

PRINT 2 : LoggerMessageProcessor: {Set-Cookie=JSESSIONID=F60114E3ECB450A62171E3D63EAC3E4D; Path=/bonita/; HttpOnly}

PRINT 3 : Response code 401 mapped as failure. Message payload is of type: BufferInputStream

```
<http:request-config name="bos" host="localhost"
    port="8080" basePath="/bonita" doc:name="bos-connection" />


<flow name="sendOrderFlow">

    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration"
        path="/" doc:name="HTTP" />

    <http:request config-ref="bos" path="loginservice"
        method="GET" followRedirects="false" doc:name="bos-login">
        <http:request-builder>
            <http:query-param paramName="username" value="walter.bates" />
            <http:query-param paramName="password" value="bpm" />
        </http:request-builder>

    </http:request>

    <copy-properties propertyName="JSESSIONID" /> <!-- PRINT 1 HERE -->
    <logger message="#[headers:INBOUND:Set-Cookie]" level="INFO" />  <!-- PRINT 2 HERE -->

    <http:request config-ref="bos"
        path="API/bpm/process" method="GET" followRedirects="false" doc:name="bos-listAvailableProcesses">
        <http:request-builder>
            <http:query-param paramName="p" value="0" />
        </http:request-builder>
    </http:request>
```

Comment: puh ... no idea anoyone ? -.-

Answer (score 0):

Additionally to JSESSIONID you also need to include X-Bonita-API-Token in HTTP header. The value of this header is provide as a cookie sent with the answer to the authentication (i.e. the call to loginservice).